# Fetching previous entry if particular date value doesn't exist

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I want to Fetch Value for the last entry if entry doesn't exist on that date.

For Example:-

Currently what is happening, if i change date to previous and the record doesn't exist is shows me today's or the record which is displayed already. But I want to show last entered record in case the record does not exist.

Another Example..

```
DATE     |   GOAL
17       |   320 
16       |   420
13       |   300
```

If user is pressing previous button and he is on 16 then user should get 13 date value on 15, As no Value exist for 15.

Comment: You want the row with the DATE = `SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM table WHERE  DATE <= _your_value_`.

Comment: Actually i want value for lower date.. if no entry for 14th  then it shows me value of 13th  or less than that date

Comment: just using loop when the cursor is empty, lower the current parameter. using loop or recursive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WHERE to ignore all rows with a later date, then take the row with the largest remaining date:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Date <= *the_value*
ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggested solution as code and [in a fiddle for you to check](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6cdd/2)

```
select *
from table1 
where date_col = (
  select max(date_col)
  from table1
  where date_col <= *the_value*)
  ;
```